# escape variable in bash script curl request

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I am trying to curl via bash script but unable to pass the value of var1 in curl request and getting error upon execution ...

```
 #!/bin/bash
 var1="some test message"
 curl 'https://link' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '
{"msgtype": "text", 
  "text": {
      "content": $var1
   }
}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below script.

```
https://aaa.com' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"msgtype": "text", "text": {      "content": '"'$var1'"'   }}'
```

Comment: This produces invalid JSON that uses single quotes to quote the value of the `content` key. Using parameter expansion to create JSON is not in general safe anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `$var1` doesn't get expanded by the shell because it is inside single quote `'`.

You need to use double quote to let bash do the parameter expansion, and escape your json data:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="some test message"
curl 'https://link' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d "
{
  \"msgtype\": \"text\", 
  \"text\": {
    \"content\": \"$var1\"
  }
}"
```

Or you can use inline document (without the escaping hell, but the command becomes awkward):

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="some test message"
curl 'https://link' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d "$(cat <<EOT
{
  "msgtype": "text", 
  "text": {
    "content": "$var1"
  }
}
EOT
)"
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, don't use parameter expansion to define JSON dynamically like this. There is no guarantee that your template, combined with the contents of the variable, produces well-formed JSON. (This is for the same reasons you don't use string interpolation to create dynamic SQL queries.) Use a tool like `jq` instead.

```
curl 'https://link' ... \
  -d "$(jq --argjson x "$var" \
           -n '{msgtype: "text", text: {content: $x}}')"
```